# Typedef a class with specific constructor argument

Tags: c++, typedef

Lets start with a simple class in C++ :

```
class aClass {
        bool b;
        aClass(bool x){b=x;} 
};
```

Is it possible to typedef  2 new types  stateTrue and stateFalse so that if I do:

```
stateTrue variable;
```

it would translate to:

```
aClass  variable(true);
```

?

Comment: A `typedef` introduces an alias for an existing type. If you want new types based on `aClass` you'll need more than a `typedef`.

Comment: You are trying to mix compile time constructs (type) with runtime values (value of the member `b`). What is the proble that you *really* need solved? By knowing the problem rather than the issue with your intended solution you might get better answers.

Comment: Well, I'm writing an program that solves a particular equation. The class would represent an "upper" or "lower" state. The typedef part would be for easier readability of the code when the particular state is needed.

Comment: Use static const globals then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to inheritance could be to make `aClass` a `template`:

```
template <bool T>
class aClass
{
public:
    bool b;
    aClass(): b(T) {}
};

typedef aClass<true>  stateTrue;
typedef aClass<false> stateFalse;
```

Comment: Indeed.  Although there's little benefit in having the `b` member variable now!

Answer (score 0):

No, because that's an instance, not a type.

You could derive:

```
class stateTrue: public aClass {
public:
    stateTrue() : aClass(true) {}
};
```

Comment: This works, and I don't have a better answer, but personally I don't care for it...  In my use case, it seemed ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be

```
class stateTrue : // new type needed, not just a new name
  public aClass { // but obviously can be converted to aClass
  public: stateTrue() : aClass(true) { } // Default ctor sets aClass base to true
};
```